# Vaadin 23 and client side regex validation

Tags: regex, vaadin, textfield

After getting into the new Vaadin 23 version, I've seen that the combinaison setPattern/setPreventInvalidInput has been replaced by setPattern/setAllowedCharPattern but the behaviour is not the same. How can I, in the new Vaadin version, prevent the user from entering an invalid value on the client side using a regular expression ? I need the user not to be able the enter data that is not valid for the regex.

Example :

```
tf.setPattern("(\\d){0,5}");
tf.setPreventInvalidInput(false);
```

The user cannot enter more than 5 numbers, which is the expected behaviour.

```
tf.setPattern("(\\d){0,5}");
tf.setAllowedCharPattern("\\d");
```

The user can enter more than 5 numbers, the field will be set as invalid, but the behaviour is not the same as before.

Is there a way of achieving the same as with setPreventInvalidInput using Vaadin 23/24 functionalities ?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't necessarily replace the functionality for all possible regular expressions, but if your goal is to prevent the user from actually typing any more than 5 numbers, as in your example, then you can keep this part that only allows digits:

```
tf.setAllowedCharPattern("\\d");
```

And add a max length:

```
tf.setMaxLength(5);
```

Then users won't be able to type more than 5 numeric digits in the text field. You won't get the nice shaking effect on the field that you do when you try to type a non-number, but the user will be prevented from typing more than 5 characters (and can only type numbers, due to the regex).

Alternatively, you could just use the same thing you were using, but set the setPreventInvalidInput() method to true (it was false in your example):

```
tf.setPattern("\\d{0,5}");
tf.setPreventInvalidInput(true);
```

This still works, although the setPreventInvalidInput() method is deprecated, so possibly a concern going forward, since it looks like it will be removed in a future version of Vaadin, possibly 24.

Playing around with this a little more, I suspect that the reason this was deprecated is that it has unpredictable effects on the input. For example, a simple regular expression like "ab" which should allow "ab" does not allow any input, because the regex pattern has to match the entire string, and obviously you can't type "ab" with one character so no characters are allowed at all. This view is supported by this comment on [a related GitHub issue](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/4307#issuecomment-1340982930) and discussion in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/2986).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, unfortunately the regex is quite more complex than the one I wrote in the example, so I really need the same functionality. Btw, why does this functionality disappeared in the latest version ?
Imagine the user enters a thousand separator, the max length won't be able to handle that. It's also possible to create a server side validator, but for such an easy task, I feel it's more correct to use client side validation.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit to provide an alternative approach and more details on why this feature was deprecated.

Comment: Ok, I understand now why they don't like this method, but the feature itself cannot be replaced and breaks a lot of user friendlyness imo. Thanks for the links I wasn't aware of, I just added a comment to get some more help on the vaadin side directly

Comment: If I remember correctly we deprecated the method exactly for the reason @mlarson described. Developers regularly used pattern and preventInvalidInput in a way that no input was possible (https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/3837). Since the main goal of preventInvalidInput was to allow only entering specific characters, we introduced allowedCharPattern instead. If you want, you can file an enhancement ticket for your specific use-case.

Comment: Thank you Sascha for your input, I've file an issue in the vaadin github : https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/5306